# D3 stacked bar graph, with each stack a different colour set by the different groups,

Tags: javascript, d3.js, colors, stack, key

**The problem**

I am trying to get a stacked bar graph in D3 (v5) to have individually coloured bar for different groups (that I can do, Fig 1), with each stack a different colour (depending on the Fig 2).

[image: Figure 1: bars coloured by Group e.g. "Domestic" (Grey) and "Marine" (Dark Green)]

[image: Figure 2: bars coloured by Stack level ("key") A, B, C, D.]

I can't find a way to get the stack colouring (i.e. I want different shades of the Group colour to vary with the different stack height) example in Fig 3 (except I'd like the different groups to be different colours i.e. not repeating as they are here).

[image: Figure 3. An illustration of where I am trying to get to.]

In the code examples I have provided there are two sets of data. A simple set, to help play with the data:

```
Animal,Group,A,B,C,D
Dog,Domestic,10,10,20,5
Cat,Domestic,20,5,10,10
Mouse,Pest,75,5,35,0 
Lion,Africa,5,5,30,25
Elephant,Africa,15,15,20,20
Whale,Marine,35,20,10,45
Shark,Marine,45,55,0, 60
Fish,Marine,20, 5,30,10
```

And [a bigger set](https://gist.github.com/JimMaltby/844ca313589e488b249b86ead0d621a9) that I am actually trying to use.
Here is the [`bl.ocks.org`](http://bl.ocks.org/JimMaltby/844ca313589e488b249b86ead0d621a9) code that I'm trying to develop:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {
    top: 90,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 960 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, height])
  .padding(0.1);
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]);
const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["none", "lightsteelblue", "steelblue", "darksteelblue"]);

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JimMaltby/844ca313589e488b249b86ead0d621a9/raw/f328ad6291ffd3c9767a2dbdba5ce8ade59a5dfa/TimeBarDummyFormat.csv", d3.autoType, (d, i, columns) => {
      var i = 3;
      var t = 0;
      for (; i < columns.length; ++i)
        t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
      d.total = t;
      return d;
    }

  ).then(function(data) {
    const keys = data.columns.slice(3); // takes the column names, ignoring the first 3 items = ["EarlyMin","EarlyAll", "LateAll", "LateMax"]

    // List of groups = species here = value of the first column called group -> I show them on the X axis
    const Groups = d3.map(data, d => d.Group);
    y.domain(data.map(d => d.Ser));
    x.domain([2000, d3.max(data, d => d.total)]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", d => z(d.key)) //Color is assigned here because you want everyone for the series to be the same color
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(d => d)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("y", d => y(d.data.Ser))
      .attr("x", d => x(d[0]))
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("width", d => x(d[1]) - x(d[0]));

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .call(d3.axisTop(x));

    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  });
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: rgb(70, 131, 180);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/yq7bkvdL/

**What I’ve tried**

I feel like I am just missing something simple, but I am a coding noob and my coding is pretty rudimentary so I can't work it out.

I think I am either placing the fill `attr` in the wrong place. Or it's that I don't understand how to select the key in the nested/hierarchical data of `d3.stack`.

I have tried various things, all with no success:

**1. Array of colours**
I have tried writing a function to create an array of the colours, by iterating (with `forEach`) over the "key" and the "Group" values/names and concatenate them to create an array that I can use with the d3 Scale (ordinal) to select the correct colour. For example with the first dataset it would  create an array `ColoursID` `[DomesticA, DomesticB, DomesticC, DomesticD,PestA, PestB...]` which then matches up to the colours in `ColourS`  `["grey", "lightgreen", "green", "darkgreen", "yellow", ...]`

Below is the attempt to do this, plus various other explorations commented out.

```
  // List of groups = species here = value of the first column called group -> I show them on the X axis
  const stack = d3.stack().keys(stackKeys)(data);

//const Groups = d3.map(data, d => d.Group);
//const ColourID = d3.map(data, d => d.Group && d.key);
//  const stackID = stack.data // //stack[3].key = "D" // [2][6].data.Group  = "Marine"
// const Test1 = Object.entries(stack).forEach(d => d.key);
        
const stackB = stack.forEach(function(d,i,j){
                                                //var a =  Object.keys(d)//= list of 3rd Level keys "0,..7,key,index"
                                                //var a =  Object.keys(d).forEach((key) => key) "undefined"
                                                //var   a = d.key //= "D" for all
                        d.forEach(function(d,i){
                                            //var a =  d.keys // = "function keys{} ([native code])"
                          //var a =  Object.keys(d)
                          //var a =  Object.keys(d) //= list of 2nd Level keys "0,1,data"
                                                    var  b = data[i]["Group"]   
                                    d.forEach(function(d){
                                                    //var a = [d]["key"] // = "undefined"
                          //var a = Object.keys(d).forEach((key) => d[key]) // = "undefined"
                              var a = Object.keys(d) //= ""
                           //   var a =  d.keys //= "undefined"
                                data[i]["colourID"] = b + " a" + "-b " + a //d.key
                                                                })  
                        })    
               });
  
  console.log(stack)
```

```
      svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(stack)
        .enter().append("g")   
        //.attr("fill", d => z(d.data.Group) ) //Color is assigned here because you want everyone for the series to be the same color
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(d => d)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("fill", d => colourZ(d.data.colourID)) //Color is assigned here because you want each Group to be a different colour **how do you vary the blocks?**
        .attr("y", d => y(d.data.Animal) )      //uses the Column of data Animal to seperate bars
        .attr("x", d=> x(d[0]) )                //
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )         //
        .attr("width", d=> x(d[1]) - x(d[0]));  //
```

VizHub code: https://vizhub.com/JimMaltby/373f1dbb42ad453787dc0055dee7db81?file=index.js

**2. Create a second colour scale:**

I used the advice in here ([d3.js-adding different colors to one bar in stacked bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280898/d3-js-adding-different-colors-to-one-bar-in-stacked-bar-chart)), adding an if function to select a different colour scale, by adding this code:

```
//-----------------------------BARS------------------------------//

      // append the rectangles for the bar chart
      svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("g")
        .data(stack)
        .enter().append("g")      

            //Color is assigned here because you want everyone for the series to be the same color
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(d => d)
        .enter().append("rect")
        .attr("fill", d => 
              d.data.Group == "Infrastructure" 
              ? z2(d.key) 
              : z(d.key))
        //.attr("class", "bar")
        .attr("y", d => y(d.data.Ser) )         //Vert2Hor **x to y** **x(d.data.Ser) to y(d.data.Ser)**
        .attr("x", d=> x(d[0]) )                //Vert2Hor **y to x** **y(d[1]) to x(d[0])**
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth() )         //Vert2Hor **"width" to "height"**  **x.bandwidth to y.bandwidth** 
        .attr("width", d=> x(d[1]) - x(d[0]));  //Vert2Hor **"height" to "width"**  **y(d[0]) - y(d[1]) to x(d[1]) - x(d[0])**
```

[VizHub code](https://vizhub.com/JimMaltby/8efe6f2c81184fb9bdcaa785482ae146?file=index.js#L92)

**3. A big IF function in fill.**

If this is the solution I would appreciate some advice on
**a.** making it work, then **b.** having a more efficient way of doing it

Here again it  seems I am struggling to select the "key" of the "stack" data array. You'll note that I have been trying different ways to select the key in the code here, with no success :(.

```
        .attr("fill", function(d,i, j) {        
            if (d.data.Group === "Domestic") {
                if (d.key === "A") { return "none"}
                    else if (d.key === "B") { return "lightblue"}
                    else if (d.key === "C") { return "blue"}
                else if (d.key === "D") { return "darkblue"}
                else  { return "forestgreen"}
            }
            else if (d.data.Group === "Pest") {
                if (d.key === "A") { return "yellow"}
                    else if (d.key === "B") { return "lightorange"}
                    else if (d.key === "C") { return "orange"}
                else if (d.key === "D") { return "darkorange"}
                else  { return "Brown"} //"yellow", "lightorange", "orange", ""
            }
            else if (d.data.Group === "Africa") {
                if (Object.keys(root.data) === 1) { return "grey"}
                    else if (d.key === "B") { return "lightred"}
                    else if (d.key === "C") { return "red"}
                else if (d.key === "D") { return "darkred"}
                else  { return "pink"}
            }
            else if (d.data.Group == "Marine") {
                if (stackKeys == "A") { return "lightgrey"}
                    else if (stackKeys[d] == "B") { return "lightblue"}
                    else if (stackKeys[i] == "C") { return "blue"}
                else if (stackKeys[3] == "D") { return "darkblue"}
                else  { return "steelblue"}
            }
            else { return "black" }             
                ;})
```

Code in [Viz Hub](https://vizhub.com/JimMaltby/4d6ac53ef0ca4cfb90f6e22975a7c933?file=index.js&mode=full#L81)

Comment: So you are attempting to base the fill on whether the stack is a,b,c, or d?

Comment: Actually would it be possible for you to start a jsfiddle?

Comment: While it's awesome how much effort you put into formulating and researching your question, it isn't clear to me where to look. Of the 4 code examples you shared, I assume the bl.ocks.org one is the base to start working from. However, FYI - while your comments may make sense to you, they make your code more convoluted and harder to understand for outsiders. Please confirm that the code I inlined (from the bl.ocks.org example, I removed some non-essential things) is the basis you started from?

Comment: @RubenHelsloot the code you have inlined is the basis I started from. Thanks for your perseverance, in spite of my commenting.

Comment: And what you're looking for is for all segments to have different colours? So a chart of 4 stacks of 3 bars each has not 3, but 12 colours?

Comment: Kind of. What I am looking for is that the 4 stacks have a predefined set of colours, that is the same for others from the same group (e.g. in the inline code data 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ...). But that the colours change for another set of colours for other groups (e.g. 2.5, 2.6, etc stacks are varying hues of green, then 3.10, 3.11, 3.12, etc stacks are each varying hues of red). In the example figure the bands of stacks with similar colours, would not repeat colours they would be different as they are different groups. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to vary the bar colours slightly if the bars are of smaller length, you can use `fill-opacity` and keep the `fill` the same! This way, the colours are less pronounced and lighter if the value is lighter.

Just create a new scale `opacity` with range `[0.3, 1]`. I chose 0.3 because 0 opacity means the bar is invisible, and you generally don't want that. I added a separate value `d.height` to denote the entire visible height of the bar, which is separate from start (but equivalent to `d.Min + d.All + d.Max`). Now, just apply the attribute to every bar and you're done.

You can choose to set the range to `[0, 1]` and not use `d3.extent` for the domain - that will probably lead to similar results, though there are some differences which you can spot with a thought experiment.

Right now the `fill-opacity` attribute is set on every bar. So the bars in the same stack have the same `fill-opacity` value. Note that this is entirely optional, though, and you can also apply distinct values.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {
    top: 90,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 960 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, height])
  .padding(0.1);
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]);
const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["none", "lightsteelblue", "steelblue", "darksteelblue"]);
const opacity = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0.3, 1]);

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JimMaltby/844ca313589e488b249b86ead0d621a9/raw/f328ad6291ffd3c9767a2dbdba5ce8ade59a5dfa/TimeBarDummyFormat.csv", d3.autoType, (d, i, columns) => {
      var i = 3;
      var t = 0;
      for (; i < columns.length; ++i)
        t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
      d.total = t;
      d.height = d.total - d.Start;
      return d;
    }

  ).then(function(data) {
    const keys = data.columns.slice(3); // takes the column names, ignoring the first 3 items = ["EarlyMin","EarlyAll", "LateAll", "LateMax"]

    // List of groups = species here = value of the first column called group -> I show them on the X axis
    const Groups = d3.map(data, d => d.Group);
    y.domain(data.map(d => d.Ser));
    x.domain([2000, d3.max(data, d => d.total)]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);
    opacity.domain(d3.extent(data, d => d.height));
    console.log(opacity.domain());

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill", d => z(d.key))
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(d => d)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("y", d => y(d.data.Ser))
      .attr("x", d => x(d[0]))
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("width", d => x(d[1]) - x(d[0]))
      .attr("fill-opacity", d => opacity(d.data.height));

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .call(d3.axisTop(x));

    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  });
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: rgb(70, 131, 180);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

---

**Edit**: knowing that you want to colour the bars by group, I would use the same logic, but make a few adjustments:

For one, I switched `z` to deal with `fill-opacity` (which I still use to accentuate the different groups), and use a new ordinal scale `group` for the colours. The key to that scale is simply the pre-existing field `d.Group`.

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {
    top: 90,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 960 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, height])
  .padding(0.1);
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]);
const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]);
const group = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["darkgreen", "darkred", "steelblue", "purple"]);

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JimMaltby/844ca313589e488b249b86ead0d621a9/raw/f328ad6291ffd3c9767a2dbdba5ce8ade59a5dfa/TimeBarDummyFormat.csv", d3.autoType, (d, i, columns) => {
      var i = 3;
      var t = 0;
      for (; i < columns.length; ++i)
        t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
      d.total = t;
      return d;
    }

  ).then(function(data) {
    const keys = data.columns.slice(3); // takes the column names, ignoring the first 3 items = ["EarlyMin","EarlyAll", "LateAll", "LateMax"]

    y.domain(data.map(d => d.Ser));
    x.domain([2000, d3.max(data, d => d.total)]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);
    group.domain(data.map(d => d.Group));

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("fill-opacity", d => z(d.key))
      .selectAll("rect")
      .data(d => d)
      .enter()
      .append("rect")
      .attr("y", d => y(d.data.Ser))
      .attr("x", d => x(d[0]))
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("width", d => x(d[1]) - x(d[0]))
      .attr("fill", d => group(d.data.Group));
      

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .call(d3.axisTop(x));

    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  });
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: rgb(70, 131, 180);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

---

**Edit 2**: if you want to specify the colours yourself, I would use a map of keys to colours:

```js
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
const margin = {
    top: 90,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 960 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

const svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

const y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, height])
  .padding(0.1);
const x = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([0, width]);
const z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range([0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]);
const group = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range([
    { Start: "none", Min: "lightgreen", All: "green", Max: "darkgreen" },
    { Start: "none", Min: "indianred", All: "red", Max: "darkred" },
    { Start: "none", Min: "lightsteelblue", All: "steelblue", Max: "darksteelblue" }
  ]);

d3.csv("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/JimMaltby/844ca313589e488b249b86ead0d621a9/raw/f328ad6291ffd3c9767a2dbdba5ce8ade59a5dfa/TimeBarDummyFormat.csv", d3.autoType, (d, i, columns) => {
      var i = 3;
      var t = 0;
      for (; i < columns.length; ++i)
        t += d[columns[i]] = +d[columns[i]];
      d.total = t;
      return d;
    }

  ).then(function(data) {
    const keys = data.columns.slice(3); // takes the column names, ignoring the first 3 items = ["EarlyMin","EarlyAll", "LateAll", "LateMax"]

    y.domain(data.map(d => d.Ser));
    x.domain([2000, d3.max(data, d => d.total)]).nice();
    z.domain(keys);
    group.domain(data.map(d => d.Group));

    svg.append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(d3.stack().keys(keys)(data))
      .enter().append("g")
      .each(function(e) {
        d3.select(this)
          .selectAll("rect")
          .data(d => d)
          .enter()
          .append("rect")
          .attr("y", d => y(d.data.Ser))
          .attr("x", d => x(d[0]))
          .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
          .attr("width", d => x(d[1]) - x(d[0]))
          .attr("fill", d => group(d.data.Group)[e.key]);
      });
      

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0,0)")
      .call(d3.axisTop(x));

    svg.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
  });
```

```css
.bar {
  fill: rgb(70, 131, 180);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>
```

Comment: Sorry I mustn’t have been clear in my explanation. This isn’t what I am trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I have added clarification of that in the comments above. If I understand this correctly this varies the opacity of each of the bars by the ‘d.data.height’ for each stack.

Comment: I've added a new answer, using groups

Comment: Cool that’s much closer to what I am after but ideally I would like to have more control over the colours i.e. so I can pick specific colours for the individual stack in each group. Is that possible?

Comment: It feels like I need some way to set the .fill in both the .append(“g”) and the .append(“rect”) with some kind of IF function. But I am guessing there is a simpler way to do this.

Comment: Or is there a way to use the .range from “z” to select a .range from group (or the other way around)?

Comment: What do you mean by have more control? Control the colour of one individual bar or of a group of bars? It sounded like you wanted all bars in the group to have related colours. And yes, scales are not magic, they return just a string or a number, and you can then do anything with that. Including passing it to another scale!

Comment: What I mean is to prescribe the colour for 1st , 2nd, 3rd and 4th stack for each group, for example. So the fill colours of each stack level are fixed, but change depending on the group designation.

Comment: And yes, sorry if I confused you, I do want some of them to be related colours, but I want to be able to define the relationship myself not automatically - as there are some exceptions.

Comment: Just so I understand what's going on here.  Rather than doing a ```.fill``` before the ```.selectAll"rect"``` as here: ```.enter().append("g").attr("fill", d => z(d.key)).selectAll("rect")```  We are effectively creating a loop for each bar with the ``` .each(function(e) {  d3.select(this)``` as per:  ```.enter().append("g").each(function(e){d3.select(this).selectAll("rect")``` . Is that correct? Is there a good place to understand better how the ```.each``` and ```d3.select(this)``` are working?

Comment: That is correct. The best place to learn about those is the [d3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/API.md), or examples you can find on [observablehq](https://observablehq.com/)